# System.JSONException while using the SObjectFabricator library

Tags: apex, json, apexmock

I am using the SObjectFabricator library (https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) in order to fabricate/create an object with relationships for mocking purposes.

I have two Sobjects Routing_Rule__c and Routing_Rule_Parameter__c that have a parent-child/master-detail relationship. That is there is a Routing_Rule__c field on the Routing_Rule_Parameter__c  object that goes back to the Routing_Rule__c object.

Following the documentation I have the following:

```
//Parent Object
 sfab_FabricatedSObject fabricatedrr1 = new sfab_FabricatedSObject(Routing_Rule__c.class);
    fabricatedrr1.setField(Routing_Rule__c.Id, getFakeId(Schema.Routing_Rule__c.SObjectType));

//Child Object
    sfab_FabricatedSObject fabricatedrrp1 = new sfab_FabricatedSObject(Routing_Rule_Parameter__c.class);  
    fabricatedrrp1.setField(Routing_Rule_Parameter__c.Id, getFakeId(Schema.Routing_Rule_Parameter__c.SObjectType));

//I set the name to 'Routing_Rule_Parameters' because that is what it says on Child Relationship Name
    fabricatedrr1.setChildren('Routing_Rule_Parameters', new List<sfab_FabricatedSObject> {fabricatedrrp1});

    //======================problematic line======================
    Routing_Rule__c rr1 = (Routing_Rule__c)fabricatedrr1.toSObject();
```

I get:

```
System.JSONException: No field name specified on column for sobject of type Routing_Rule__c
```

The stack trace:

```
Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1
Class.sfab_FabricatedSObject.toSObject: line 39, column 1
```

Looking further the code on Class.sfab_FabricatedSObject.toSObject is :

```
public SObject toSObject() {
        system.debug('serialize() is (later to be deserialized): '+serialize());
        return (SObject)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(serialize()), sType);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have been looking at this for a couple of hours now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely here (we use sfab_xxx throughout our org):

```
fabricatedrr1.setChildren('Routing_Rule_Parameters', new List<sfab_FabricatedSObject> {fabricatedrrp1});
```

You need to use the API name of the relationship, which is most likely

```
fabricatedrr1.setChildren('Routing_Rule_Parameters__r', new List<sfab_FabricatedSObject> {fabricatedrrp1});
```

Relationship names for parents or children are case sensitive when used with sfab (which in turn uses JSON.deserialize)

Comment: Ahhh that was it !!!!!!!!   Thanks so much